# How to iterate through column and only return one variable in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been trying to compare a column in a DataFrame to a list and find the differences. The only problem is, when I do this, it gives the list of differences, but puts an entry for each column.

For example:

```
def Type():
    list1=['Dog','Cat','Monkey','Horse', 'Giraffe']
    list2=Zoo['Animal'].values.tolist()     
    new_list = (set(list1).difference(set(list2)))
    return new_list    

Zoo['Animal Type'] = Zoo.apply(lambda row: Type(), axis = 1)
Zoo['Animal Type']
```

returns

```
34     {Cat, Monkey, Dog, Horse}
38     {Cat, Monkey, Dog, Horse}
39     {Cat, Monkey, Dog, Horse}
41     {Cat, Monkey, Dog, Horse}
46     {Cat, Monkey, Dog, Horse}
47     {Cat, Monkey, Dog, Horse}
48     {Cat, Monkey, Dog, Horse}
49     {Cat, Monkey, Dog, Horse}
```

instead of a final list of differences at the end like:

```
0 Cat
1 Monkey
2 Dog
3 Horse
```

I only want each difference to be stated once in the output. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Where do you use `row` in your `Type` function?

Comment: Sorry about that, I copied another block of my code and edited it for this example. I edited it out and updated the example. I'm using the column 'Animal' from the DataFrame 'Zoo' which was made from reading a csv.

Comment: I think you can do this differently... Try... `zoo.loc[~zoo['Animal Type'].isin(list1), 'Animal Type']`

Comment: I tried that with `Zoo['Animal Type'] = zoo.loc[~zoo['Animal'].isin(list1), 'Animal'] ` which returned the format that I need, but it just shows blank values instead of differences. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ZebraDonkey  Can you post what Zoo['Aminal Type'] looks like in question above.

Comment: Zoo['Animal'] isn't defined. It's just pulled from a csv file with a column called 'Animal' which I pull in from Zoo when needed. Animal pulls in fine when using it in Pivot Tables and other functions, it's just being difficult here